# boost::property_tree compile error (error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'p')

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm struggling to compile some code that utilises the boost property tree. I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

If I simplify the code as much as possible to reproduce the error, the code looks like the following...

```
#include "AppleiTunesLibraryImporter.h"
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
using namespace boost::property_tree;

AppleiTunesLibraryImporter::AppleiTunesLibraryImporter(){}
AppleiTunesLibraryImporter::~AppleiTunesLibraryImporter(){}

bool AppleiTunesLibraryImporter::ImportData( std::string itunes_library_xml_path )
{
    ptree pt;
    xml_parser::read_xml( itunes_library_xml_path.c_str(), pt, xml_parser::no_comments | xml_parser::trim_whitespace);
    return true;
}
```

...and the full error looks like the following...

```
1>  AppleiTunesLibraryImporter.cpp
1>c:\<path to my file>\thirdparty\boost\boost-1.47.0\boost/detail/allocator_utilities.hpp(178): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'p'
1>          c:\<path to my file>\thirdparty\boost\boost-1.47.0\boost/multi_index/detail/index_base.hpp(88) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::allocator::construct<T>(void *,const Type &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>,
1>              Type=std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\<path to my file>\thirdparty\boost\boost-1.47.0\boost/multi_index/detail/index_base.hpp(87) : while compiling class template member function 'boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<Value,Allocator> *boost::multi_index::detail::index_base<Value,IndexSpecifierList,Allocator>::insert_(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<Value,Allocator> *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Value=std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>,
1>              Allocator=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>>,
1>              IndexSpecifierList=boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<>,boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>::subs::by_name>,boost::multi_index::member_offset<std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,0>,std::less<std::string>>>,
1>              _Ty1=const std::string,
1>              _Ty2=boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>
1>          ]
1>          c:\<path to my file>\thirdparty\boost\boost-1.47.0\boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp(119) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::index_base<Value,IndexSpecifierList,Allocator>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Value=std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>,
1>              IndexSpecifierList=boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<>,boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>::subs::by_name>,boost::multi_index::member_offset<std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,0>,std::less<std::string>>>,
1>              Allocator=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\<path to my file>\thirdparty\boost\boost-1.47.0\boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp(77) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index<KeyFromValue,Compare,SuperMeta,TagList,Category>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              KeyFromValue=boost::multi_index::member_offset<std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,0>,
1>              Compare=std::less<std::string>,
1>              SuperMeta=boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<2,std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>,boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<>,boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>::subs::by_name>,boost::multi_index::member_offset<std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,0>,std::less<std::string>>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>>>,
1>              TagList=boost::mpl::vector1<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>::subs::by_name>,
1>              Category=boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_non_unique_tag
1>          ]
1>          c:\<path to my file>\thirdparty\boost\boost-1.47.0\boost/multi_index_container.hpp(89) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index<SuperMeta,TagList>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              SuperMeta=boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1,std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>,boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<>,boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>::subs::by_name>,boost::multi_index::member_offset<std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,0>,std::less<std::string>>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>>>,
1>              TagList=boost::mpl::vector0<boost::mpl::na>
1>          ]
1>          c:\<path to my file>\thirdparty\boost\boost-1.47.0\boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp(59) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<Value,IndexSpecifierList>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Value=std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>,
1>              IndexSpecifierList=boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<>,boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>::subs::by_name>,boost::multi_index::member_offset<std::pair<const std::string,boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>>,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,0>,std::less<std::string>>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\<path to my file>\thirdparty\boost\boost-1.47.0\boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp(182) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<Key,Data>::subs' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Key=std::string,
1>              Data=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\<path to my file>\thirdparty\boost\boost-1.47.0\boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp(182) : while compiling class template member function 'boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<Key,Data>::basic_ptree(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Key=std::string,
1>              Data=std::string
1>          ]
1>          ..\..\..\common\Source\AppleiTunesImporter\AppleiTunesLibraryImporter.cpp(24) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<Key,Data>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Key=std::string,
1>              Data=std::string
1>          ]
```

For me, line 24 of my ApplieiTunesLibraryImporter.cpp file is just

```
ptree pt;
```

so, the compiler is not liking my use of it. I can get similar errors when I use something like

```
ptree::const_assoc_iterator assoc_iter;
```

but the above code is the simplest I can make the error happen.

The code inside the boost file (allocator_utilities.hpp) that is causing the compilation error looks like the following, but it's quite cryptic to me.

```
/* allocator-independent versions of construct and destroy */

template<typename Type>
void construct(void* p,const Type& t)
{
  new (p) Type(t);
}
```

In case someone wants to try and reproduce, here is the .h code.

```
class AppleiTunesLibraryImporter
{
public:

    AppleiTunesLibraryImporter();
    virtual ~AppleiTunesLibraryImporter();

    bool ImportData( std::string itunes_library_xml_path );

};
```

This has all turned into a bit of brain melt so if anyone can shed some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: I need more code - instead of posting part of the error message and part of the code, boil your problem down into something that you can post full code for so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Zac. You're right, I was missing some useful info, so I've edited the original post to make it more complete. Thanks.

Comment: You should try to reproduce this without any additions and provide a single compilable snippet that reproduces the problem. For me, http://ideone.com/FhfsS works perfectly on gcc with boost 1.49

Comment: I have the exact same code compiling fine on mac (gcc 4.0) and with LLVM. It's windows that is causing me grief. By 'additions', are you referring to the use of the xml_parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem. The project I'm working on makes use of precompiled headers and for the .cpp files that are using boost libs, I had to prevent this from happening. In other words, I had to right click on the .cpp file an go...

> Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Precompiled Headers

and set "Precompiled Headers" to "Not Using Precompiled Headers"
Also, go to...

> Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Advanced

and set "Forced Include File" to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and since solution above is not applicable for me. I had to find the root cause. When I found it to my annoyance I realized that it's not the first time I've done this investigation :). So this time no mistake and documenting the root cause here :).
I suspect it's the same root cause the author had. 
So in my case the problem was that somewhere in headers which are included as part of Precompiled one there was

```
#define new .... // Debugging memory leaks in debug
```

This definition coming through precompiled headers screws up placement new.

Since it's problematic to throw away this definition("political" reasons). The best way I could found in my case

```
#pragma push_macro("new")
#undef new
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/info_parser.hpp>
#pragma pop_macro("new")
```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer!